# Проблема с event.object.text

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api

token = 'токен'

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()

vk.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, id)

while True:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.object.peer_id == event.object.from_id:
                    if event.object.text.lower() == 'слово':
                        vk.messages.sent(message='BOT MESSAGE')
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

А если пишу `if event.object.text() == 'слово':` то пишет:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Answer (score 2):

В объекте `event.object` нет атрибута `text`, поэтому вместо него возвращается `None`. А у `None` нет метода `lower`, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Скорее всего, Вам нужен объект `event.obj['message']` и такие его поля, как `peer_id` и `text`.

К тому же, Вы в дальнейшем неправильно обрабатываете сообщение. У Вас опечатка в названии метода `messages.send` и отсутствуют обязательные поля.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


vk_session = VkApi(token='token')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'group_id')
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        message = event.obj['message']

        peer_id = message['peer_id']
        text = message['text']

        if text.lower() == 'word':
            vk.messages.send(
                peer_id=peer_id,
                message='Test message',
                random_id=get_random_id(),
            )
```